# Running valgrind 32bit binaries on 64 bit machine

Tags: linux, valgrind

I'm trying to run valgrind 32bit binaries on 64 bit machine(linux) and i'm getting this error:

> valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'x86-linux': No
>   such file or directory

What do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: If you don't have `memcheck-x86-linux` file (e.g. in `/usr/lib/valgrind`), then your valgrind built without x86 support.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here a year later. I tried installing valgrind from source and I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have installed Valgrind for analysing 32-bit programs on your Linux distribution.

For example on Ubuntu 15.04, installing Valgrind via

```
apt-get install valgrind
```

installs both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Valgrind analytical tools:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-*
/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
```

What is you Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by setting `VALGRIND_LIB` to Valgrind's library path (eg. `/usr/local/lib/valgrind`) in my `.bashrc`:

```
export VALGRIND_LIB="/usr/local/lib/valgrind"
```

I don't know why this is not mentioned in the [Valgrind Installation Instructions](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html) or why I had to add this following these instructions, however I found this hint in the [README_DEVELOPERS](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=blob;f=README_DEVELOPERS;h=07a48c4941a205fb2908dcd5b0ab6a2ea8621d46;hb=HEAD) shipped with the sources.